# Excel Macro find rows in list and replace data from another list

Tags: excel, vba

Im wondering if theres a way in VBA to have a macro check the SKU and Store from "SheetB" and if found in "SheetA" Then replace the "STORE", "PRODUCT_TYPE" and "CONCAT" columns with the info from "SheetB" (in blue) and loop through the table if new ones are added.

***Example:*** All rows with Sku: 95908352 and Store: -1 in SheetA will have its information changed to the blue columns on "SheetB".
**SheetA STORE** will be replace by **SheetB Store(Autofill)**, **SheetA PRODUCT_TYPE** will be replaced by **SheetB Product Type (Autofill)** and **SheetA CONCAT** will be replaced by **SheetB Move to**.

Then loop through the list if more exceptions are added to the SheetB table.

**SheetA (Before):**

[image]

**SheetB:**

[image]

**Sheet A (After):**

[image]

```
Dim wsD As Worksheet, wsE As Worksheet, r As Long
Dim rngData As Range, rngEx As Range, mH, mR, col As Long, hdr, v
Dim rngCopy As Range, lr As Long, addr

Set wsD = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
Set wsE = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SKU Exceptions")

Set rngData = wsD.Range("A3:Z" & wsD.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)


For col = 1 To 3  'loop the columns on the exceptions sheet
    lr = wsE.Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
    If lr > 1 Then
    
    
    
    
        'get the values and find on "Data"
        hdr = Replace(wsE.Cells(1, col).Value, "Product Type (Move to) ", "")
        hdr2 = Replace(wsE.Cells(1, col).Value, "Store (Autofill) ", "")
        mH = Application.Match(hdr, rngData.Columns(17), 0) And Application.Match(hdr2, rngData.Columns(1), 0)

        If Not IsError(mH) Then 'matched both values?
            For r = 2 To lr
                v = wsE.Cells(r, col).Value
                mR = Application.Match(v, rngData.Columns(17), 0)
                If Not IsError(mR) Then
                    'Copy new values over
                    

                    
                Else
                    'value was not matched
                    MsgBox "Value '" & v & "' not found on Data sheet!"
                End If
            Next r
        Else
            'header not matched
            MsgBox "Header '" & hdr & "' not found on data sheet!"
        End If
    End If
Next col

MsgBox "Sku's have been reordered successfully!", vbInformation, "Reorder Sku's Macro"
```

Comment: You can use a loop for this - have you tried anything?  If Yes - what specific problems are you having getting it to work?  If No - maybe try something?

Comment: @TimWilliams A little complex for me so Ive tried modifying your response from a previous problem of mine to tailor it for this. Stuck on copying the information once matching records; Ill update my questions with what I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When matching on >1 column it's often easier to use a Scripting Dictionary to create a map of composite keys and corresponding rows:

```vb
Sub Test()

    Dim wsD As Worksheet, wsE As Worksheet
    Dim rngData As Range, rngEx As Range, rwEx As Range
    Dim dict As Object, rwD As Range, rwE As Range, k
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    Set wsD = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    Set rngData = wsD.Range("A3:Z" & wsD.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    Set wsE = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SKU Exceptions")
    Set rngEx = wsE.Range("A2:E" & wsE.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    'Map exception rows to composite key of `store~~SKU`,
    '   assuming combination is unique...
    For Each rwE In rngEx.Rows
        k = rwE.Cells(1).Value & "~~" & rwE.Cells(2).Value
        dict.Add k, rwE
    Next rwE
    
    'loop the data rows and check for matching exceptions
    For Each rwD In rngData.Rows
        k = rwD.Cells(1).Value & "~~" & rwD.Cells(3).Value 'composite key
        If dict.exists(k) Then
            Set rwEx = dict(k)
            rwD.Cells(1).Value = rwEx.Cells(4).Value
            rwD.Cells(2).Value = rwEx.Cells(5).Value
        End If
    Next rwD
    
    MsgBox "Sku's have been reordered successfully!", vbInformation, "Reorder Sku's Macro"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Another separate question; what would I change this `Set rngEx = wsE.Range("A2:D" & wsE.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))` to if it were looking at a string/text and not a number? Otherwise, it fails on this line.

Comment: Typo - was missing the `.Row` (as for `rngData`)  Fixed above.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly....

```
Sub test()
Dim wsD As Worksheet, wsE As Worksheet
Dim rgE As Range, cell As Range, rgStore As Range, rgR As Range

Set wsD = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
Set wsE = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SKU Exceptions")
Set rgE = wsE.Range("B2", wsE.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown))

For Each cell In rgE
    If Not wsD.Columns(3).Find(cell.Value) Is Nothing Then
        With wsD.Columns(3)
        .Replace cell.Value, True, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
        Set rgStore = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical).Offset(0, -2)
        .Replace True, cell.Value, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
        End With

        If Not rgStore.Find(cell.Offset(0, -1).Value) Is Nothing Then
        
            With rgStore
            .Replace cell.Offset(0, -1).Value, True, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
            Set rgR = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical)
            .Replace True, cell.Offset(0, -1).Value, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
            End With

            rgR.Value = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
            rgR.Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Offset(0, 3).Value
            rgR.Offset(0, 13).Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    
        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

The sub create rgE which is the range of wsE column SKU from B2 to end of row. Then it looped to each cell within rgE.

During the loop, it check if the looped cell value is found in wsD column 3, then it set rgStore variable. So, rgStore is the range in column A of wsD, where rgStore's cell offset(0,2) value is the looped cell value.

Next, it check if the looped cell.offset(0,-1) value is found in rgStore, then it set rgR variable. So, rgR is the range in column A of wsD, where rgR's cell value is the looped cell.offset(0,-1).value and the cell.offset(0,2) value is the looped cell value.

Finally it fill the needed result.

Not tested with dummy data.

Comment: It does work, however it fails on the last "End If" but still changes the data properly. Any idea why it may be failing on that line?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't figure out why it fails on the last "End If", and I also unable to figure what kind of fail. Because in my mind it should not fail as the last "end if" is just to "finish it" if the looped cell value is not found in wsD column 3. It's just something like "if found then do ..... if not found then do nothing".